# Returning values with an else statement

Tags: python, function, if-statement, for-loop, return

In my code below, the last for loop decides if there is a match or not.  If there is a match, I would like to return the track title, if there is not a match, I would like to return w

```
import requests
import json

# initial message
message = "if i can\'t let it go out of my mind"

# split into list
split_message = message.split()

def decrementList(words):
    for w in [words] + [words[:-x] for x in range(1,len(words))]:
        url = 'http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q='
        request = requests.get(url + "%20".join(w))

        json_dict = json.loads(request.content)
        num_results = json_dict['info']['num_results']

        if num_results > 0:
            num_removed = len(words) - len(w)

            track_title = ' '.join(words)

            #track_title = "If I Can't Take It with Me"

            for value in json_dict["tracks"]:
                if value["name"] == track_title:
                    return track_title
                else:
                    return w

            return num_removed, json_dict, track_title, w


num_words_removed, json_dict, track_title, w = decrementList(split_message)
```

Unfortunately, this is not my ideal solution.  I would really like to rerun the shortened list of words until there is a track match.  I tried this:

```
for value in json_dict["tracks"]:
    if value["name"] == track_title:
        return track_title
    else:
        decrementList(w)
```

But, I got some sort of infinite loop and timed out my request.  It makes sense in my head.  If there is no track match, take the shortened list, stored in "w" and rerun it through the decrementList function.

So, I guess I have two questions.  How can I return two values in an else statement, and how can I rerun the shortened list until I find a track match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to consider what you want to return.  Seems you didn't make up your mind on that one because sometimes you return a single value (`track_title`, `w`), sometimes you return a tuple (`num_removed, json_dict, track_title, w`).  This I cannot do for you and it depends on what you need later.

Besides that, I think you should use a generator to yield results until the caller is satisfied (the best first, then decreasing match quality, i. e. with lesser and lesser matching words).  Have a look at my version of your code:

```
import requests
import json

# initial message
message = "if i can't let it go out of my mind"

# split into list
split_message = message.split()

def decrementList(words):
    for w in [ words ] + [ words[:-x] for x in range(1, len(words)) ]:
        url = 'http://ws.spotify.com/search/1/track.json?q='
        request = requests.get(url + "%20".join(w))

        json_dict = json.loads(request.content)
        num_results = json_dict['info']['num_results']

        if num_results > 0:
            num_removed = len(words) - len(w)

            track_title = ' '.join(w)

            for track in json_dict["tracks"]:
                if track["name"].lower().startswith(track_title.lower()):
                    yield num_removed, track, track["name"], w

def quote(s):
   return '"' + ('%r' % ("'"+s.encode('utf-8')))[2:]

for num_words_removed, track, track_name, w in decrementList(split_message):
   print '%2d %s by %s (track %d on %s from %s)' % (
     num_words_removed,
     quote(track_name),
     quote(track['artists'][0]['name']),
     int(track['track-number']),
     quote(track['album']['name']),
     track['album']['released'])
```

Comment: You can of course remove the line `if value…` to also get the results which do not exactly start with the wording of the abbreviated query.  This way you will also get the "If I Can't Take It with Me".

Comment: hi, thanks for this.  a few parts confuse me. i will have a look though!